# Race condition when connecting with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, coffeescript, mongoose, bluebird

```
connect = (uri) ->
  new Promise (resolve, reject) ->
    db = mongoose.connection
    db.on "error", reject
    db.on "open", resolve
    mongoose.connect uri

connect(MONGO_URI[NODE_ENV]).then ->
  console.log "Connected to #{NODE_ENV}"
  MyModel.find().exec().then (models) ->
    console.log models.length
```

This results in a race condition where the number of documents returned is random and short of the complete number in the collection. If, however, I wrap the `find` in a delay (say, 3 seconds), I get all of the documents. But I was under the impression that I wouldn't run into a race condition like that if I wait for the "open" event. I'm using Bluebird promises, fwiw, but I get the same result if I forego promises and just use callbacks.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with my code. This appears to be related to [this issue](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/609), because when I comment out all unique indexes in my schema, it works. This is a (still unresolved) [bug](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4462) in the MongoDB driver.